# How to detect what went wrong with my Winform application?

Tags: wpf, winforms, exception

Few of the users of my Winform based WPF application are getting this error- "**myApp has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.**"

I believe this error is not thrown by application code so I am not able to log/handle it and figure out what is causing this to happen.

Any one has an idea how to diagnose such issues?

Comment: This is an extremely vague question. My only advice would be to check the event log of the Windows machine's with problems and see if any errors were raised there.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Event Viewer for the exception which occurred in your code. The most likely cause of it is that there is a thread in your app which doesn't have try/catch and the exception is closing the whole program.
If you share the exception from Event Viewer (eventvwr.msc) the solution should be easy

Answer (score 1):

Write an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event and log or display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can provide more information we can only make the most general "[How Do I  Debug](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html#id2790282)"-type suggestions:

- Can you duplicate the problem? If so,  run the app in a debugger.
- If you can't duplicate the problem you will have to get your users to do so. You should make a special debug version of your app that logs what it is doing periodically. Get your users to trigger the error and send you the log.
- Narrow down what is causing the problem by removing sections of code, or building test app with only the suspect sections of code.
- Do not presuppose what is causing the problem. Do you have any evidence this is a WPF or WinForms error? Why do you "believe this error is not thrown by application code "? You need evidence, not guesses.